# Let $y'=f(x,y)$ an ODE. If $y'(x)=0$ for a certain $x$, then $y(x)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my course, I have the ODE $$y'(x)=2x-2xy^2,$$
and in the solution it's written

Since we are intrest to non trivial solution, $1-y^2\neq 0$ for all $x$ (other wise, $y(x)=0$ for all $x$), and thus

$$y'(x)=2x-2xy^2\iff \frac{y'(x)}{1-y^2(x)}=2x.$$

**So my question is:** If $y'=f(x,y)$ and if $y'(x)=0$ for a certain $x$, then $y(x)=0$ for all $x$ ? If yes, how can I prove it ? does it hold for equation of higher degree ?

**This is how I solve the Cauchy problem:**
$$
\begin{cases}
y'=2x-2xy^2\\
y(0)=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$

Let $x$ s.t. $y(x)\neq \pm 1$.
$$y'=2x-2xy^2\iff \ln\left|\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right|=2x^2+D$$
Since $y$ is continuous, we have either $y<-1$ or $-1<y<1$ or $y>1$. But since $y(0)=1/2$, we necessarily have $-1<y<1$. Then

$$\ln\left|\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right|=\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{y-1}\right)$$ and thus, the general solution is of the form $$y(x)=\frac{Ae^{2x^2}-1}{Ae^{2x^2}+1}.$$
It's easy to show that $A=3$ and thus that the solution is given by $y(x)=\frac{3e^{2x^2}-1}{3e^{2x^2}+1}$, and since it's define for all $\mathbb R$, the solution is $y:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ define by $y(x)=\frac{3e^{2x^2}-1}{3e^{2x^2}+1}$

**Question : Is may way to solve it fine and rigorous enough ?**

Comment: No it is not necessary at all and hence cannot be proved.

Comment: ok, so why it work here ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of function $y'=f(x,y)$ is. Moreover, in this case also, I think your book has a typo. It should have read: "(otherwise $y(x)=1$ for all $x$)"

Comment: @Aniket: Or $-1$.

Comment: @HansLundmark You are right. I had realised it but couldn't edit it as my comment had got 5 min. old. Yours is right.

Comment: The key fact here is that $f(x,\pm1)=0$ **for every $x$** hence, indeed, if $y(x)=\pm1$ for some $x$ then $y(x)=\pm1$ for every $x$. This does not hold for every function $f$, for example the solution of $y'(x)=x+y(x)-1$ such that $y(0)=1$ is $y(x)=e^x-x$, which is not identically $1$.

Comment: @Did :So in my Cauchy problem, if $y(0)=1$, the only solution is $y(x)=1$ for all $x$ ? And what do you think about my resolution ? is it rigorous enough and correct ? Thank you :-)

Comment: Well, some $e^{2x}$ should read $e^{2x^2}$ but the idea is there, yes. What saves the day is that your differential equation is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_differential_equations#Separable_first-order_ordinary_differential_equations).

Comment: thank you very very much to have illuminated me.

Answer (score 2):

The trivial solution, i.e. $y(x)=0$, doesn't solve your problem at all, since in this case $y'=0\ne 2x=2x-2x\cdot 0^2$
$y(x)=1$ does solve your problem.

A differential equation may have more then one solution, therefore it is often coupled with additional equations, called (initial\boundary) condition.  Which helps to determine which of many solution (if at all) is of interest.
In some cases this condition may lead to zero solution, but in general it doesn't have to be so.

Comment: I made an up date. Is may way to solve is correct and rigorous enough ?

Comment: looks fine for me, but as a general advise, the more details the better(not here, but when you submit it if this is your assignments or so). For example i would add something between implicit and explicit formula for $y(x)$ and also show why $A=3$. This is for the case you do a mistake - one can judge the matter of the mistake, if it is hidden the immediate assumption would be "because you don't know what you do".

Comment: Great, thank you very much :-) I actually did it, but it was a little bit long to write all details here.